# how do I get two separated arrays from on one large array containing obejcts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

here I have one array of data

[{"TRANSACTION_ID":"DQ==","TRANSACTION_AMOUNT":"1300"},
  {"TRANSACTION_ID":"Dg==","TRANSACTION_AMOUNT":"1400"},

{"TRANSACTION_ID":"Dw==","TRANSACTION_AMOUNT":"1500"},

{"TRANSACTION_ID":"EA==","TRANSACTION_AMOUNT":"1600"},
 {"TRANSACTION_ID":"EQ==","TRANSACTION_AMOUNT":"1700"},

{"TRANSACTION_ID":"Eg==","TRANSACTION_AMOUNT":"1800"},

{"TRANSACTION_ID":"Ew==","TRANSACTION_AMOUNT":"1900"},

{"TRANSACTION_ID":"FA==","TRANSACTION_AMOUNT":"2000"}]
I want separate the value of TRANSACTION_ID in one separated array and TRANSACTION_AMOUNT in another separated array in javascript. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
const transactionIDs = originalArray.map((transaction) => transaction.TRANSACTION_ID);
const transactionAmounts = originalArray.map((transaction) => transaction.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the entries and push to the same properties.

```js
var data = [{ TRANSACTION_ID: "DQ==", TRANSACTION_AMOUNT: "1300" }, { TRANSACTION_ID: "Dg==", TRANSACTION_AMOUNT: "1400" }, { TRANSACTION_ID: "Dw==", TRANSACTION_AMOUNT: "1500" }, { TRANSACTION_ID: "EA==", TRANSACTION_AMOUNT: "1600" }, { TRANSACTION_ID: "EQ==", TRANSACTION_AMOUNT: "1700" }, { TRANSACTION_ID: "Eg==", TRANSACTION_AMOUNT: "1800" }, { TRANSACTION_ID: "Ew==", TRANSACTION_AMOUNT: "1900" }, { TRANSACTION_ID: "FA==", TRANSACTION_AMOUNT: "2000" }],
    { TRANSACTION_ID: ids, TRANSACTION_AMOUNT: amounts } = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => (r[k] = r[k] || []).push(v));
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(...ids);
console.log(...amounts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not fast as the accepted answer but still here it is.

```
let array1 = [];
let array2 = [];
data.forEach((element) => {
  array1.push(element.TRANSACTION_ID);
  array2.push(element.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT);
});
```